# Get values from updated data in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem on deriving the data from UPDATED table. Anyone here to help me to solve this.

i have following tables

### repairs

repair_id(pk), 
repair_details, 
total_cost,

### parts

parts_code(pk), 
part_name, 
unit_price,

### repairs_parts

id(pk), 
repair_id(fk), 
part_code(fk), 
part_quantity,

---

i created trigger to sum total cost of repair and set that value in repairs attribute 'total_cost' i.e.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER repairs_parts_trigger on repairs_parts for INSERT, 
    UPDATE AS   
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @repair_id INT; 
    SET @repair_id = 'SELECT repair_id from INSERTED';

    DECLARE @total_parts_cost float;

        SET @total_parts_cost = 'SELECT SUM(p.unit_price * rp.part_quantity) 
        AS total FROM  repairs_parts rp, parts p, repair r WHERE 
        rp.part_code = p.part_code AND r.repair_id = rs.repair_id  and 
        repair_id = @repair_id';

        UPDATE repairs SET total_cost = @total_parts_cost where repair_id = 
        @repair_id

    END;
```

After creating that trigger, every time when i update the quantity of parts in repairs_parts table, it return an error

```
    Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure repairs_parts_trigger, Line 4 
    [Batch Start Line 248]
    Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT repair_id 
    from INSERTED' to data type int.
```

Please Please help me to solve this. Is anything did i write in wrong way or is there any other way to solve this problem??

Comment: your statement will attempt to set the value of total_parts_cost to a string (i.e. the string `SELECT SUM(p.unit_price...` etc). What you want I think is to set the value to the _result_ of that query, not to the query itself.

Comment: Try `SELECT @total_parts_cost = SUM(p.unit_price * rp.part_quantity) 
        AS total FROM  repairs_parts rp, parts p, repair r WHERE 
        rp.part_code = p.part_code AND r.repair_id = rs.repair_id  and 
        repair_id = @repair_id;` instead

Comment: same problem with @repair_id. Neither of those queries ever gets executed. You just write a string into a variable. The fact that string looks like a SQL query is simply coincidence as far as the code is concerned. You need to actually execute the query and assign the _result of the execution_ to the variable.

Comment: swap `= 'select ... '` for `= (select ..)` or `select @total_parts_cost = sum()....`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Thank you to all of you. The solution you've provided works :) . Thanks again

Comment: @madhusudansapkota Happy to help. Since it works, I have written my comments up into a proper answer. I would be grateful if you would mark the answer as accepted, for the benefit of future readers (and me, of course :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement will attempt to set the value of total_parts_cost to a string (i.e. the string `'SELECT SUM(p.unit_price... etc)'`. What you want I think is to set the value to the *result* of that query, not to the query itself.

Write this:

```
SELECT @total_parts_cost = SUM(p.unit_price * rp.part_quantity) AS total FROM repairs_parts rp, parts p, repair r WHERE rp.part_code = p.part_code AND r.repair_id = rs.repair_id and repair_id = @repair_id;
```

instead.

Do the same with `@repair_id` as well.

At the moment, neither of those queries ever gets executed. You just write a string into a variable. The fact that string looks like a SQL query is simply coincidence as far as the code is concerned. You need to actually execute the query and assign the *result of the execution* to the variable.

The final code should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER repairs_parts_trigger on repairs_parts for INSERT, 
UPDATE AS   
BEGIN

  DECLARE @repair_id INT; 
  SELECT @repair_id = repair_id from INSERTED;

  DECLARE @total_parts_cost float;

  SELECT @total_parts_cost = SUM(p.unit_price * rp.part_quantity) 
  AS total FROM  repairs_parts rp, parts p, repair r WHERE 
  rp.part_code = p.part_code AND r.repair_id = rs.repair_id and 
  repair_id = @repair_id;

  UPDATE repairs SET total_cost = @total_parts_cost where repair_id = 
  @repair_id

END;
```

Also note the comment suggesting to use newer-style JOIN statements. I would suggest too that it's probably possible to condense this down into 2 queries, or even 1, which might prove to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below modified code-

```
Alter TRIGGER repairs_parts_trigger on Catalog for INSERT, 
UPDATE AS   
BEGIN

DECLARE @repair_id INT; 
 SELECT @repair_id = repair_id from INSERTED

DECLARE @total_parts_cost float;

    SELECT @total_parts_cost = SUM(p.unit_price * rp.part_quantity) 
    FROM  repairs_parts rp, parts p, repair r WHERE 
    rp.part_code = p.part_code AND r.repair_id = rs.repair_id  and 
    repair_id = @repair_id 

    UPDATE repairs SET total_cost = @total_parts_cost where repair_id = 
    @repair_id

END;
```